# How can I instantiate objects with gaps between all objects?

Tags: unity, c#

When instantiate each a new object I want it to be with the same gaps from also the other instantiated objects.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairsUnits : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Stairs Units Prefab")]
    public GameObject stairsUnitsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Settings")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfUnits = 1;
    public static GameObject Unit;
    public int gap = 10;

    private int oldNumberOfUnits = 0;
    private List<GameObject> units = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject unitsParent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;

        unitsParent = GameObject.Find("Stairs Units");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
        {
            Unit = Instantiate(stairsUnitsPrefab, unitsParent.transform);
            Unit.name = "Stairs " + i.ToString();
            Unit.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(gap, 0, gap);
            units.Add(Unit);
            Unit.AddComponent<MoveObjects>();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (numberOfUnits < oldNumberOfUnits)
        {
            Destroy(units[units.Count - 1]);
            units.RemoveAt(units.Count - 1);

            oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = oldNumberOfUnits; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
            {
                Unit = Instantiate(stairsUnitsPrefab, unitsParent.transform);
                Unit.name = "Stairs " + i.ToString();
                Unit.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(gap, 0, gap);
                units.Add(Unit);
                Unit.AddComponent<MoveObjects>();
            }

            oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried in both places to add a localPosition with gap/s:

```
Unit.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(gap, 0, gap);
```

But they are still all at same position.

Comment: Did you mean to write `(i + 1f) * (new Vector3(gap, 0, gap))` so that the position increases by `gap` each time `i` increases by 1?

Comment: I did. But now I see that the position of each Unit is something else on x and z but yet all the Units at the same position when running the game.  If I look on each unit in the inspector it have another position x and z but when running the game they are all at the same place. I can move each unit with the mouse.